# javascript polymorphism refactoring

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, refactoring

I have an object that maps properties to functions, something like this:

```
var objFunctions = {
  prop1: func1,
  prop2: func2,
  prop3: func3,
};
```

Now, I just need a valid prop name to call the adequate function, for example

```
   var callFuncProp = 'prop1'
    objFunctions[callFuncProp]('value1');
```

This works fine, however, let's say that a new function came up, and that needs additional arguments. Dynamically calling this function with additional arguments means that all other functions would receive them

```
objFunctions[callFuncProp]('value1', 'value2', 'value3'); 
// calls func1 which defined only one parameter
```

This also works, but I really have a problem with this kind of design. How could I refactor the code so that I can still dynamically call the functions but pass only additional arguments to the functions that really expects them ? I would really like to avoid switch statement...

Comment: Maybe use different `objFunctions` for different signatures?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Where do your arguments and function names come from? How/why are they dynamic?

Comment: "Dynamically calling this function with additional arguments means that all other functions would receive them": unless your functions are the same and have identical arity, why would this be the case?